# .append() doesn't work in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Code in header:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/price.js' ); ?>" />');
  });
</script>
```

price.js:

```
var usd, eur;
$( window ).load(function getPrice() {
    var usdApi = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/USD/last";
    var euroApi = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/EUR/last";

    $.getJSON(usdApi, function(data){
      usd = data;
    });
    $.getJSON(euroApi, function(data){
      eur = data;
    });

    alert('test'); //working

    $("#usd").append(usd);
    $("#euro").append("test"); //working
});
```

However, if I write in the js-console `$("#usd").append(usd);` it works. Seems that `var usd` is present, DOM and its content loaded before running the script.

Comment: Restructure your code, because you're making AJAX Requests, read this [**AJAX SO Post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) on this issue. Remember, AJAX Is asynchronous; the `$('#usd').append()` is ran at a *different* time to which `usd` is defined.

Comment: That string you gave is invalid. `'...) . '/js/price.js' ); ?...'`. Your trying to use single quotes inside your single quotes, make sure to escape them with `\'`

Comment: @MackieeE, thanks. Just moved .append() into ajax function.